# How I get the encoding of a page before I download it?

Tags: java, attributes, character-encoding

I need get the encoding of a web page(UTF-8,ISO-8859-1,etc) before I download it because I will convert it from the InputStream downloaded to String using the encode.

I using HttpUrlConnection and there is a method called getContentEncoding, but it will return only if the server sends it.

In some cases, the encoding is in the attribute charset(HTML4?), in others in the attribute encoding(XHTML), and others I dont know, but I presume that there are another forms.

There is some class that do this or what is the way to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [HTTP 1.1 specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-7.2.1) indicates that `Content-Type` "should" be used to indicate the content, and that responses that do not include this header should be treated as "application/octet-stream" -- in other words, a sequence of bytes rather than characters. The use of "should" indicates that it's recommended practice, but some servers may not follow it.

So, your first step is to look for this header. If it's not present, don't apply any character-set decoding to the content. In the case of XML, assuming that you pass the stream on to a parser this will just work: either the stream will be UTF-8 encoded, or the prologue will specify the encoding. And you *should* always pass streams directly to an XML parser, without attempting to convert them to a string first.

If there is a `Content-Type` header, and it specifies a character set, then you're free to decode according to that character set. The spec also talks about how to deal with a [missing character set](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-3.4.1): for any `text` content type, you should assume that it is encoded using ISO-8859-1.

So that's the next step: if there's a character set, or if it's a `text` media type, apply the decoding.

Otherwise, leave the stream alone.

Comment: By example, this page (a teacher from the college): xtema.com.br. The page is encoded using UTF-8, but the header only show text/html. Following the specification, I must presume that it's encoded using ISO-8859-1, right? But if I decoded using ISO-8859-1, it's wrong because it's using UTF-8.

Comment: I took a look at the page, and see that it's using a `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type"` element within the HTML markup. A browser will be smart enough to parse that (assuming that all prior content is US-ASCII), but it's somewhat of a hack (the W3C HTML 4.0 documentation indicates that it's for use by *servers*, not clients: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#edef-META). If your goal is to write a browser that handles all the misshapen HTML on the web, then I suppose that parsing META tags is required. Otherwise, I'd say that the page doesn't follow the spec.

Comment: And if you really want to risk your grade, you might want to point your teacher at the W3C validater: http://validator.w3.org/. It doesn't call out the use of META (which is legal), but that page has plenty of other errors.

Comment: Actually I'm doing a web crawler, not a browser, and I need the charset to put the content of pages correctly in the dabatase for post-process. I'm searching for some HTML parser that extract the charset according to content specified in the page. HTMLParser extracts from header, Jsoup returns the format used in conversion from InputStream to String (by default, UTF-8). I still searching...

Comment: About the teacher, he knows that page has erros. He even teach us about the validator and the first thing we did was validate his site.

Comment: @Renato - if you want to do what the browsers do, then you need to create an `InputStream` wrapper that will switch its encoding when it discovers the meta tag. I don't know about anything that does this already, but you might find some leads on the Mozilla.org site. And if you don't find anything, ask your professor to describe the key features of a "layered architecture" ;-)

Comment: Ok, finally I found Jericho HTML Parser. I can retrieve the charset from HEADER or the specific inside the document (if they are different) with him. It show not only the charset, but the part of the html where it finds the encoding. Looks like a good tool ! :D

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could try issuing a [HEAD request](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html) to fetch the HTTP headers before attempting to fully process the page? HTTPUrlConnection has [setRequestMethod](http://cupi2.uniandes.edu.co/web/javadoc/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#setRequestMethod%28java.lang.String%29), where you could specify HEAD.

With a HEAD request, the server is supposed to return all headers but without the message body. You can try [parsing the Content-Type header value](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-headers-charset). Example headers returned from server would be:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 23 May 2005 22:38:34 GMT
Server: Apache/1.3.3.7 (Unix)  (Red-Hat/Linux)
Last-Modified: Wed, 08 Jan 2003 23:11:55 GMT
Etag: "3f80f-1b6-3e1cb03b"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 438
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

The following snippet should give you an idea of how to iterate and read the headers returned in a HEAD request.

```
int i=1;// this will print all header parameter
String hKey;
while ((hKey=conn.getHeaderFieldKey(i))!=null){
    String hVal = conn.getHeaderField(i);
    System.out.println(hKey+"="+hVal);
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Can you show me a example how I do this? I set the request to HEAD, but the result is always blank.

Comment: If the server sends the encoding he already can read it (as he says.) The problem is to parse all the variants of possible encoding declarations across all html/xhtml flavors when the server does not sent encoding headers. Is that correct @Renato?

Comment: Could he not just parse the Content-Type header? That is what the browser uses to figure out how to process the response.

Comment: Yes, I did this, but sometimes the server DON'T sends the charset part. The only thing I got is the text/html.

Comment: Looks like Anon's description says it all.

Answer (score 0):

There is no guarantee that you can do this without inspecting the document.

The [HTML 4.0.1 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/charset.html#h-5.2.2) details how to specify the encoding via the `Content-Type` HTTP header and/or the `meta` elements within the document.

In the case of XHTML served with [`Content-Type: application/xhtml+xml`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#media) the encoding must be discovered from the document.